# Gitlab CI Append To Array Each Time A Job Is Inherted From

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a job (`.enable_feature`) which other jobs can inject to produce special artifacts. These artifacts are downloaded and consumed by a downstream job (`.consume_feature`).

I would like to automatically generate the dependency list for `.consume_feature`. Ideally I could append to a list each time `.enable_feature` is inherited from. **Is this possible?**

One thing to note: our CI setup has the automatic dependencies from previous stages disabled. I can't really change this...

I.e.:

```yaml
# I cannot remove anything from this job template
.default_job:
  variables: ENABLE_FEATURE: 0
  dependencies: []

# I can change anything past this line (except for inheriting from .default_job)
feature_jobs: []

.enable_feature:
  variables: ENABLE_FEATURE: 1
  # somehow append job name to feature_jobs
  # ???

.foo:
  extends:
    - .default_job
    - .enable_feature # should somehow append .foo to feature_jobs

.bar:
  extends:
    - .default_job
    - .enable_feature # should somehow append .bar to feature_jobs

.baz:
  extends:
    - .default_job

.consume_feature:
  extends:
    - .default_job
  dependencies:
   [*feature_jobs] # I want this to expand to [foo, bar]
```

Comment: maybe i dont understand what you want todo, but cant you add this to the .consume_feature stage? `[*feature_jobs, .foo, .bar]`

Comment: Yes I could. Currently we do this by hand, but in reality we have something like 70 jobs that need to go in this array. I am looking for a way to automate this, since we just got bit in the ass from a silent bug when someone forgot to manually remove a job from the list :(

Comment: ah i see. i guess the most simple solution - adding `.enable_feature` to .consume_feature will not work.